# Callouts, spreaded across multiple pages

Tags: tables, longtable, callout

Is there a way to create a large callouts, which will spread across multiple pages?

Here is an example of very short callout made in Word:

[image]

And here is another one, large, spreaded across pages:

[image]

Not sure if I need use tables for it.

Cheers, John.

Comment: what you try so far? how "call out" should look like? see, if `tcolorbox` with option `breakable` is what you looking for.

Comment: @Zarko > how "call out" should look like --- A thick light-gray line at the left side. It is visible on my screenshots. Thanks, I will look at `tcolorbox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

[image]

with `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\newcounter{task}
\newtcolorbox{call out}%
   {enhanced jigsaw,
    breakable,
    before skip=\baselineskip,
    boxsep=0pt,
    boxrule=0mm,
    colback=white, colframe={red},
    top=0mm,bottom=0mm,left=2mm,right=0mm,
    arc=0mm,
    leftrule=2mm,
    }% end of task

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{call out}
\lipsum[4-6]
\end{call out}
\lipsum[7]
\end{document}
```